# Leaving an infinite while loop in C

Tags: c, while-loop

I have a loop that constantly reads from my serial port. The loop is infinite, so the only way I know of stopping the program is by using `Ctrl+C`. The problem with this solution, which I suspect is causing other problems as well, is that when I use `Ctrl+C`, my program ends abruptly. At the end of the program, I close the connection to the file descriptor of the serial port I am accessing, but I don't think my program ever reaches that because of me using the `Ctrl+C` command, which just stops the program exactly where it is.

Is there a way for me to create the infinite while loop, and exit when I want, but at the same time, maintain the capability to execute the code beneath it?

Comment: Which OS? You can override the ctrl-c handler, set some flag there, and then (in the infinite loop), check for the flag and break;

Comment: Use a variable that controls the while loop, e.g. `while(running)`. Just set this variable asynchronously to false to exit the loop.

Comment: @Yossarian It's Ubuntu. I don't know how to do that, can you elaborate with an answer please?

Comment: @m0skit0 What do you mean when you say set it asynchronously? Thanks.

Comment: @m0skit0 you mean to use threads?

Comment: Use conditional and break statement...You will start just after the while loop...

Comment: No need for threads, but you can use them if you want. Asynchronously means you don't know when this signal will arrive (because it's the user that sends it whenever it likes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this and see what happens:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t stop;

void
inthand(int signum)
{
    stop = 1;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    signal(SIGINT, inthand);

    while (!stop)
        pause();
    printf("exiting safely\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Ctrl-C sends a signal (SIGINT) to your process. The default action for the process is to exit when it gets it, but you can catch the signal instead and handle it gracefully.

Comment: `stop` must be `volatile`, as per the Standard.

Comment: @daknøk Does it? The compiler can't know what will happen to the global variable during the call to pause(), so it can't do any nasty optimizations with it. Theoretically I guess we can get another signal  that will break us out of pause() and then get INT after reading the value of stop but before the call to pause(), but this will not be solved by volatile, it's a race condition regardless.

Comment: During a signal handler, the processor state and memory are indeterminate. `volatile` doesn’t prevent race conditions (it *never* does), but it makes sure the variable is not cached, but instead read every time it’s used (i.e. certain compiler optimizations are disabled for `volatile` variables). The Standard explicitly says that non-local variables accessed from signal handlers should be `volatile`, and that their initial state is unspecified.

Comment: The variable can't be cached over a call to a function anyway. But yes, I see that the standard is saying that. It's silly, but let's be compliant. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the complete code example; just want to note that `unistd.h` is only required for `pause()`, so if those are removed this code works for non-POSIX systems too (i.e. Windows).

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this:

```
sig_atomic_t volatile g_running = TRUE;

void sig_handler(int signum)
{
  if (signum == SIGINT)
    g_running = FALSE;
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGINT, &sig_handler);
  while (g_running)
  {
    //your code
  }
  //cleanup code
}
```

This will catch the `SIGINT` signal generated by pressing CTRL-C and break the loop by setting `g_running` to `FALSE`. Your cleanup code is then executed

Comment: `g_running` must be of type `sig_atomic_t volatile` or another lock-free, atomic (and volatile, IIRC) type otherwise you have UB, as per the Standard.

Comment: Thanks! Art's code was more complete with the `include` statements. Gave you an upvote though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable that controls the while loop, e.g. `while(running)`. Just set this variable asynchronously to false to exit the loop.

Example:

```
volatile int running = 1;
while(running) {
    /* Your code */
}
```

So another code, let's say a callback function, does this

```
running = 0;
```

You can set this callback to intercept SIG_TERM (which is Ctrl-C by default) or any signal of your choice (except SIG_KILL which is not sent to the process).

Comment: Asynchronously? Make `int` atomic or else you’ll have a race condition and UB.

Comment: Make int atomic? Instructions are atomic, not variables. Maybe you meant `volatile`?

Comment: No, modifying or accessing an `int` is not guaranteed to be atomic. Instructions on a types that are said to be “atomic” are atomic. C++ has `std::atomic<int>`, not sure about C. C11 does have atomic types, IIRC.

Comment: You don't need atomicity in this case, no one is going to put `running` to 1 again, only 0.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the infinite while loop, create a while loop which listens/reads to boolean value in a particular file. You can edit the file to quit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using ctrl + C actually interrupts your program. To avoid that

1) Use a variable and check its state in every iteration of loop.

```
int  shouldExit  = 0;

----
----
---
while (your_condition){
  if(shouldExit == 1) {
     break;
  }

  // Your loop logic here
}
```

Then assynchronously set the variable

```
shouldExit = 1
```

when you want to exit.

Comment: Oops, both logic is kind of similar.. But I believe this is the correct logic for it and all answers will be kind of same..